# Should the "self" reference be used for iteration variables in for loops inside classes?

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, self

Title pretty much has my full question.  For example,

```
class Test():
    def foobar(self, my_list):
        for element in my_list:
            do_something()
```

OR

```
class Test():
    def foobar(self, my_list):
        for self.element in my_list:
            do_something()
```

What exactly is the difference between the two, with respect to the variable `element` or `self.element`?

I think my confusion comes from the fact that `my_list` is passed to the method, so it is not an instance of `Test`, therefore `self` would be inappropriate as `element` refers to an element of `my_list`.  But the variable `element` is being created in `Test`, so every `Test` instance will have its own `element`.

Comment: Self refers to the _instance of the object_ that owns the method you called. `self.something` refers to a variable that belongs to this instance. Local variables are not instance variables.

Comment: `every Test instance will have its own element` - that's wrong. Every invocation of the foobar() method will create a local variable called `element` that isn't attached at all to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is generally "no". The for loop is assigning the variable to point to each element in the list. When it's done, it persists outside the `for` loop. The better way would be to keep `element` a local variable, and it will go away when the method ends. But if you assign it to `self.element`, that's equivalent to `self.element = my_list[-1]` when the loop ends. Then it will persist when the method exists, and will be accessible from other methods and holders of the class instance. That's usually not what you want.